Cant see the sms omnichannel messages in the chatbot
I am trying to implement digital engagement using sms omnichannel in my org and the configuration part is complete.
Set up omnichannel with the routing configuration,queue setup.
On sending sms I am not able to see the chat in the chatbot.

On checking the omnichannel queue backlogs I am able to see the messaging session details.

But why I am I not able to see the chat messages in the chatbot and accept it.
I checked and tried this option but using enhanced conversation component added I am able to see the details there but not in the omnnichannel.

I was able to figure out the issue.
In the present service statuses I had to enable the other service channels-Live Transcript and Messaging channels.
After doing so I am able to accept the work request and initiate chat.
